# Ember, run component method once when computed in controller has finished

Tags: sorting, ember.js

I'd like to call method only once when computed in controller has finished.

Here is my `controller`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    sortProperties: ['id:desc', 'id:asc', 'value:desc', 'value:asc'],

    sortedStats: Ember.computed.sort('model', 'sortProperties'),

    actions: {
        sortBy: function(sortProperties) {
            this.set('sortProperties', [sortProperties]);
        }
    }

});
```

a `template`:

```
<div><button {{action 'sortBy' 'type:asc'}}>Asc</button><button {{action 'sortBy' 'type:desc'}}>Desc</button></div>

<h1>Chart</h1>

{{chart-bar width=500 height=200 series=sortedStats}}
```

and `component`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName: 'svg'
    draw: function() {
        // here I draw the chart
    },
    init: function() {
        this._super();
    },
    onChange: function(){
        console.log('onChange');
    }.observes('series.[]')
});
```

`onChange` is called as many times as model has properties to sort. In my example it has been called 6 times and model contains array with 5 properties. I'd like to call `onChange` when `computed.sort` in controller is done.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any reason why you are observing the sorted array and not the model?

Comment: No. There is no reason. However, changing to observing model doesn't work to me.

Comment: **Note**: my current model contains only fixtures. So, it doesn't change dynamically. My understanding is that observing model in that case doesn't trigger changes when sorting is being called since model is the same. That's why I started observing computed in order to trigger action when sorting is finished.